# Why libraries .xml s appear and then disappear?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I'm starting to use maven to handle libraries on a project which had non-maven structure first.

When I use the button "Reload all maven projects" I see on explorer how .idea/libraries gets filled of xmls, but when it ends then it starts to delete them.

Libraries are downloaded to the .m2/repository folder.

##### UPDATED 2021-11-20

Somehow it seems related to some kind of conflict on **Module and Artifact names**. I reverted some inocent changes that left the artifact definitions with proper libraries referencies.

This is an opinion: I think maven/intellij may destroy the libraries `Maven__*.xml`s if it doesn't index that they are properly used.

Comment: Do you have Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | Store generated project files externally option enabled? If so, libraries will be stored outside of the project root, under the System directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#system-directory, `external_build_system` subdirectory.

Comment: I've tried to check that option but makes no difference.

Comment: I update with some research.

Comment: Under `.idea/libraries` IDE writes libraries specified in pom.xml file. You can see them in File | Project Structure | Libraries node and their usage in a specific module under the Project Structure | Modules | <module name> | **Dependencies** tab. Do you have some problems with libraries in project? Do you store these configuration files under version control?

Comment: The whole task was to "clean" the version control files (specially checking .idea folder).
I followed some recomendations on jetbrains website on wich files were "too personal" configuration to avoid.

Since those .xml was only redundant info that was suposed to be generated from the pom dependency declarations I tried to delete them, unversion them and let maven/intellij remake on a fresh checkout.

The Project Structure items were most of the time normal until the libraries xmls didn't stay at place when reloading the project.

Comment: It is not clear what happens and what is the issue. Please submit a request at [this form](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) with IDE logs (use Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data action) after reproducing and what exactly happens with libraries xml files and the eventual problems you get with an IDE with this.